# How to push specific object values into array

Tags: javascript

I have object with keys and i want to add only specific value to array. for example given keys `[3248647, 32486481]`

```
{
  "32486479": {
    "id": "32486479",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  },
  "32486480": {
    "id": "32486480",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  },
  "32486481": {
    "id": "32486481",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  },
```

Expected result should be

```
[{
    "id": "3248647",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416,
},{
    "id": "32486481",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keys.map(k => obj[k])`

```js
const keys = [32486479, 32486481];

const obj = { "32486479": { "id": "32486479", "lat": 33, "lng": 73, "accuracy": 51, "updated_at": 1570908416 }, "32486480": { "id": "32486480", "lat": 33, "lng": 73, "accuracy": 51, "updated_at": 1570908416 }, "32486481": { "id": "32486481", "lat": 33, "lng": 73, "accuracy": 51, "updated_at": 1570908416 }};

console.log(keys.map(k => obj[k]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the Array `.map` method:

```js
const ids = [32486479, 32486481]
const data = {
  "32486479": {
    "id": "32486479",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  },
  "32486480": {
    "id": "32486480",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  },
  "32486481": {
    "id": "32486481",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  }
}

const expectedResult = [{
    "id": "32486479",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416,
},{
    "id": "32486481",
    "lat": 33,
    "lng": 73,
    "accuracy": 51,
    "updated_at": 1570908416
  }]
  
 const actualResult = ids
   // loop on the ids array and use them to access object inside data
   .map(id => data[String(id)])
   // filter falsy value
   .filter(Boolean);
 
 console.log(actualResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** using [**`Array.map(e)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) **directly** is fine as long as all keys does have a corresponding object as value in the data otherwise it would return `undefined` for the keys not found and result would have `undefined` at places.

**Better:** One answer does solve that by chaining `.filter` for falsey values.

**Another solution:** [**`for...of`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) on the keys `array` to find and push into result.

```js
const keysArr = [3248647, 32486481];
let result = [];

const data = {
  "32486479": {
    id: "32486479",
    lat: 33,
    lng: 73,
    accuracy: 51,
    updated_at: 1570908416
  },
  "32486480": {
    id: "32486480",
    lat: 33,
    lng: 73,
    accuracy: 51,
    updated_at: 1570908416
  },
  "32486481": {
    id: "32486481",
    lat: 33,
    lng: 73,
    accuracy: 51,
    updated_at: 1570908416
  }
};

for (const key of keysArr) {
  if (data[key]) {
    result.push(data[key]);
  }
}

console.info("RESULT::", result);
```